# Create a timeline in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I’m creating a react native app for crop music files, it is possible to do a « timeline » for crop the song like the timeline of the iPhone gallery video editor ? There is packages for do that or elements ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-timeline-listview

a little bit of google answered that question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misspoke I meant a Trimmer for the audio. I found the package react-native-trimmer but it not working very well. So I created my own package and it’s working.